# Differential equations question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the equation $y=\ln(1+(y')^2)$.When I tried to solve this,I told my teacher that this is a Lagrange differential equation and he told me I was wrong. How can this be solved like a non-Lagrange equation? Should I put $p=y'$?

Comment: What specifically is a "Lagrange differential equation"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the traditional solution:

We have $1+y'^2=e^y$, $y'=\sqrt{e^y-1}$, $dy/\sqrt{e^y-1}=dt$, $2\arctan{\sqrt{e^y-1}}=t+c$ hence $e^y-1=\tan^2((t+c)/2)$, $y=\ln(1+\tan^2((t+c)/2))$